# Loading all data at once in template (costly?)

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

1. Present all [member] names to the user,
2. When user clicks a [member], the history of that [member] is displayed.

My approach is to select all the members, load their names in the template, and load each member's history in collapsed divs. (member's history is recorded in related models)

I'm testing this with 3 users, what if there are 20,000 users? and each user has hundreds of historical records? Would this approach be costly? Should I stay the course or is there an alternative approach I should take?

Any help/direction would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: ajax.  Select some (first 10, 20 or 100) members, when user pages down ajax-load another 100  (also provide a filter/search against members so user doesn't need to page down 200 times to get to the bottom).  When user selects a member, ajax-load that member's history.

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm assuming when I place member history in a collapsed div, it is nothing like ajax, everything is already loaded, except that it is hidden. Is this the case? If so, then ajax is an alternative I have to study now. Thanks,

Comment: @freedomn-m is suggesting infinite scroll, you can use pagination as well.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  When you pre-load as described in the question, all the data is on the page, but you get a massive hit on load - eg if each history record is 1k (with markup etc), that's 2Gb of data!!!    Not going to happen.  And how much of that does your user actually want to see at any time - maybe 1 or 2 records? With smaller data, pre-loading can make the page more responsive, but better to design for larger data up-front if it's a possibility.  So by ajax-ing the page, you only load the data your user needs.